# Unity C# gameobject.setactive(false) in first play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I set `gameobject(myCanvas)` to be `false` during the first play?
I've put this script into the cube, and when I click the cube it will show the `Canvas`.
I haven't been clicking on the cube but, the canvas has already come out.

---

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class MouseDownText : MonoBehaviour {

    public Canvas myCanvas;

    void Start()
    {
        // first start game. gameobject will turn off
        myCanvas.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    void OnMouseDown()
    {
        // for switch on/off
        myCanvas.gameObject.SetActive(!myCanvas.gameObject.activeSelf);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the inspector to see if the value of the canvas is true. As I recall the inspector takes presedence over the script.

Comment: Eeerm...Kent, Unity isn't going to serialize whether a GameObject is active or not. Usually the problem people run into with serialization is when they have an initial value on a public field, then change it in the script without realizing Unity recorded the initial value in the editor.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you have a canvas component attached to a game object (a cube) and you want to use mouse clicks to toggle whether or not the canvas is active.

Have you tried:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class MouseDownText : MonoBehaviour {

public Canvas myCanvas;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    myCanvas = GetComponent<Canvas> ();
    myCanvas.enabled = false;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void OnMouseDown()
{
    // for switch on/off

    if (myCanvas.enabled)
        myCanvas.enabled = false;
    else
        myCanvas.enabled = true;
}
}
```

Also make sure you haven't accidentally enabled it in some other code somewhere.

Comment: a cube cant show/hide text. this the problem -> MissingComponentException: There is no 'Canvas' attached to the "Cube" game object, but a script is trying to access it.
You probably need to add a Canvas to the game object "Cube". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.
MouseDownText.OnMouseDown () (at Assets/MouseDownText.cs:25)
UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32, Int32)... i already attach canvas to the script (public Canvas) to the cube . [MY Screenshot](http://i67.tinypic.com/v5e8aq.jpg)

Comment: You need to attach a Canvas component by clicking on the add component button, then click on layouts then canvas.  You will then see a canvas component in the inspector.  Then the script will work.  I'm not sure what you are using the canvas for.  The way you have it set up in the screen shot you are setting the property in your script to some canvas but I don't know what object it is a component of.  This is not the same as having a component on the cube object.  So in short add a canvas component to the cube object.

Comment: this my screenshoot (Hierarchy) [cube and canvas](http://i66.tinypic.com/ke7vgp.jpg) ............. my canvas into the cube [script into cube](http://i66.tinypic.com/oup578.jpg)........... problem when play [problem](http://i67.tinypic.com/2rz5mwl.jpg)

Comment: Ok I see your hierarchy now.  Try just using myCanvas = GameObject.Find("Canvas") and then do myCanvas.SetActive(true/false) to enable or disable.  You might want to give the canvas a unique name instead of just canvas and then use that name in GameObject.Find(whatever name you use);